# URL Shortener that forwards GET Query Strings

Tags: url, url-shortening

I want to create a small URL like `goo.gl/xpto` but I need it to forward the query string back to the original URL:

```
goo.gl/xpto?foo=bar => example.com?foo=bar
```

Which URL shortners do this nowadays?

Comment: Why would you need this? I mean, the shortener can handle a URL with query strings.

Comment: @Alex: Well, to make the URL short and dynamic of course. Say I have the URL http://goo.gl/wb7QM that points to `http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=672x420&cht=v&chco=FF6342,ADDE63,63C6DE,000000&chds=77500,5510000&chd=t:5510000,2790000,1990000,118000,1260000,77500,115000&chdl=Sagan%7CCox%7CFeynman`. It would be useful to be able to do **`http://goo.gl/wb7QM?chs=480x300`** to get `http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=672x420&cht=v&chco=FF6342,ADDE63,63C6DE,000000&chds=77500,5510000&chd=t:5510000,2790000,1990000,118000,1260000,77500,115000&chdl=Sagan%7CCox%7CFeynman&chs=480x300`.

Comment: @Alex: That's just an example of course, there are many other valid ones (e-commerce catalog listings, ...).

Comment: You can use fragments: http://goo.gl/xpto#foo=bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found one: [SnipURL](http://snurl.com/). There's just one small problem:

- http://snurl.com/277769h?chs=240x150
- http://snurl.com/277769h&chs=240x150

If I use a `?`, the generated URL comes out as:

```
http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?...&chdl=Sagan%7CCox%7CFeynman?chs=240x150
```

I need to use the `&` to start the query string:

```
http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?...&chdl=Sagan%7CCox%7CFeynman&chs=240x150
```